# Display Error: The display template had an error. SharePoint 2013 Search

Tags: search

```
Display Error: The display template had an error. You can correct it by fixing the template or by changing the display template used in either the Web Part properties or Result Types.

Template '~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Control_SearchResults.js' not found or has syntax errors. (LoadTemplate: )
```

I am getting this error when searching on our sharepoint 2013 website.
I've already enabled SearchWebParts on my site.

Comment: In case the answer posted below doesn't solve your problem, do paste your code here to get a better clarity of what might be causing the issue.

Comment: There is no custom code what I can see @MancyDesaee. The error message is pointing at the `Control_SearchResults.js` is missing from master page gallery..

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the HTML or the JavaScript that you have written on the new display template and that is the reason why this error is fired.

Once you fix them and refresh the page, the error should be solved.

Comment: There is no custom template, I didn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

There are some issues in the JavaScript or it can be spelling mismatch of the js file or the file which you referred into Web Part properties may me mismatch.

Comment: There is no custom template, I didn't change anything.